# How to put values of datagridview view to listview c#

Tags: c#, listview, datagridview

I have a DataGridView store data from DataTable get from SQL database. This step is nothing error. But when I try to get all data in DataGridView into ListView, it always say that: "Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when running to code line add data to listview.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Sample_SignIn
    {
        public partial class game : Form
        {
            SqlConnection con;
            public game()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.100.49;Initial Catalog=Chatlan;User ID=sa;Password=sa2014");
            }

            private void game_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }

                DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                String str = "select CauHoi from CauHoi";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);

                SqlDataAdapter sqldata = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);

                sqldata.Fill(dtbl);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtbl;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
//This line make an error "Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
                        listView1.Items.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }                                              
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        return;
                    }                        
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio, place a breakpoint on that line, hover your mouse over each property and check if any of the properties are null.

Comment: I put a breakpoint and try debug. But... it's not make sense anything. Everything just fine and not null any where..

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is just put the DataGridView's AllowUserToAddRows property to false.